# Why can't the getter/setter properties be reversed in Python?

Tags: python, properties

I am trying to understand how the property decorator works in Python. The code below fails because the getter/setter decorator is in the wrong order and therefore (I assume) the email property object has not been defined yet.

```
class ReverseProperties:
    def __init__(self):
        self._email = None

    @email.setter
    def email(self, value):
        self._email = value

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self._email
```

I understand that the decorators above are sort-of equivalent to this:

```
def get_email(self):
    return self._email

email = property(get_email)

def set_email(self, value):
    self._email = value

email = email.setter(set_email)
```

But when using the property decorator, where is `email` stored for us to be able to use the `@email.setter` decorator? What exactly is happening in the class when these decorators are used?

Answer (score 2):

Functions are first class in python so think of them like any other value. The property decorator wraps this up, but it's still just an object. So it's stored in the email property essentially. When seen from the class level (i.e. not bound to an instance) email is an object with a setter attribute.

As you (mostly) showed in your example, property wraps a method. When using the decorator form it's roughly equivalent to:

```
def email(self):
    return self._email

email = property(email)

def set_email(self, value):
    self._email = value

email = email.setter(set_email)
```

Technically it's something more along the lines of this non-valid python:

```
email = property(def(self): return self._email)
email = email.setter(def(self, value): self._email = value)
```

The name of the variable that is being assigned to is the name taken from the def statement. The function wrapping the function/method is that which follows the `@`. Finally, you can either think of it as the outer wrapping function getting "accessed" first or the function definition not saving to a name before it gets wrapped which is why the following is valid (i.e. why email doesn't turn back into a function before getting used as email.setter):

```
@email.setter
def email(self, value):
    self._email = value
```

Answer (score 2):

A property is a simple object, with a get-method a set-method and a del-method.

The decorator syntax is simply a convenient way to define a property, but you first have to create the property itself. So

```
@property
def email(self):
    ...
```

defines the property and sets the get-method.

```
@email.setter
def email(self, value):
    ...
```

takes the property `email` and sets the set-method.

You in principle can reverse this, but then you have to do the defining step separately:

```
class ReverseProperties:
    def __init__(self):
        self._email = None

    email = property() # define the property

    @email.setter
    def email(self, value):
        self._email = value

    @email.getter
    def email(self):
        return self._email
```

Comment: THis is great! Thx, Daniel! :)